# hide empty rows in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am displaying files in a tableview. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, I want to display only certain types of files.

I am doing something like this:

```
    if (document is folder) {
       display folder details;
    } 
    else (document is not folder) {
       display empty cell;
     }
```

by doing this i can display empty cells but those are still there(hidden) how to get rid of those rows. see the pic for details.

[image]

Comment: Consider using UITableViewStyleGrouped, it should hide empty cells

Comment: Maybe change the architecture a bit and check the data (on being a folder or not) before you bind to the UITableView? That seems more efficient, based on the information given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 'hide' cells you will need to first create an array of only Folders. Your not really going to hide cells, but rather only include the correct objects in your tables datasource array.

In your `viewDidLoad`, iterate though your entire documents array and add any Folders to a separate folderArray like so:

```
_folderArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for(Document *doc in documentsArray)
{
    if(doc is a folder)
    {
        [_folderArray addObject:doc];
    }
}
```

Use that folderArray in your all of your tableView delegate & datasource methods instead of the documentsArray.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to right direction. I knew i was doing it wrong but couldn't figure out what. :|

Answer (score 2):

I think you should rethink the problem, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should never be called for a cell that does not exist. Determine how many folders are available in your data set and return that number in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`

Then you don't need to worry about hiding it once `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is reached because it is a real cell that should be created.

Comment: Thanks. This and answer below helped. :)